# Want to avoid address reusability

Tags: transactions, ether

I want to avoid address reuse.

Suppose i received `1 Eth` in address `A` from Alice and later i want to send this `1 Ether` to Bob using another address `B`.

Is this possible that i can send funds received in one address through another address directly?

or i need to do some intermediary step to transfer money from address `A` to address `B`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this possible that i can send funds received in one address through another address directly?

It is possible if B is a smart contract, but it will cost you more comparing to just sending ether from A to B (an external account) first then sending ether from B to Bob.

However sending ether from A to B wouldn't make much difference in terms of security, unless A was used before for sending ether (which would expose your public key). It wouldn't make much difference in terms of privacy either since A and B are directly connected so you can know the source of ether sent to A.

Instead a technique such as [CoinJoin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CoinJoin) or [CoinShuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CoinJoin#CoinShuffle) can be used to anonymize transactions. Here is an example of services utilizing this technique: [ethermixer.com](https://ethermixer.com/), [weimixer.com](https://weimixer.com/)

---

A cheaper alternative is to use Zcash (a cryptocurrency aimed at improving anonymity) with a ZcashRelay contract (similar to [BTCRelay](http://btcrelay.org/)):

> Eth #1 -> Zcash #1 -> Zcash #2 -> Eth #2

Here is an interesting video talking about Ethereum and Zcash integration https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PCW2EaBjVPs

Another option proposed [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2699/is-there-any-ether-mixer-tumbler-available) is to use ShapeShift with Monero (a crypto specializing in anonymity):

> Eth #1 -> Shapeshift -> Monero #1 -> Monero #2 -> Shapeshift -> Eth #2

Otherwise you just need to avoid using the same address for receiving ether.

Comment: If i reuse same address multiple times for sending, it will only cause linkability/deanonymization? or it can also disclose my private key corresponding to that address?

Comment: In Bitcoin and Ethereum, sending from an address will reveal the public key easily. Quantum computers compromise ECDSA and would make it easy to deduce the private key from the public key: this is usually the concern about revealing the public key. Until a reasonable sized quantum computer is created there is no security risk https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1114/is-it-safe-to-reuse-ether-addresses